# Is it possible to have different authentication mode for SQL Server Database Engine and corresponding SQL Server instance?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, authentication

I have installed the x64 SQL Server 2008 R2 Express with default settings and run MBSA 2.3 Microsoft analizer (using default settings too). Tried on clean Windows 8 installation (not 8.1) and Windows 7 with the same result. It shows three SQL Server instances:

- MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS
- SQLEXPRESS
- SQLEXPRESS (32-bit)

I don't understand why there are three of them (SQL Server Configuration Manager shows only one). For the first, authentication mode is Windows, for the rest two - mixed. [Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/03e470dc-874d-476d-849b-c805acf5b24d/sql-mbsa-question-on-folder-permission?forum=sqlsecurity) is the question about such multiple instances was asked and the answer is that "MSSQL10.TEST_DB is the instance ID for the SQL Server Database Engine of the instance, TEST_DB", so in my case, it seems that MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS is the instance ID for SQL Server Database Engine  of the SQLEXPRESS instance.

I have two questions:

1. How can it be that SQL Server Database Engine instance has different authentication mode than corresponding SQL Server Instance?
2. Why 32-bit instance reported although I installed only 64-bit version?

Also, [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/security/en-US/6b12c019-eaf0-402c-ab40-51d31dce968f/mbsa-23-reporting-sql-32bt-instance-is-running-in-mixed-mode-when-it-is-set-to-integrated?forum=MBSA) question seems to be related to this issue, but there is no answer :(.

**UPD**: corrected the question, now it should be clearer

**UPD2**: SQL Server 2008 Discovery Report:[image]

**UPD3**: MBSA Report screenshots:[image][image]

**UPD4**: MBSA Report for SQLEXPRESS (32-bit) instance:
[image]

Comment: Sorry, but your question is very unclear - the SQL Server installation process creates a single instance.  It sounds like you have multiple instances installed, and our expecting them to magically be setup the same?

Comment: @MaxVernon: Yes, it creates a single instance. SQl Server Configuration Manager shows only one instance too. In fact, the only thing that shows more than one instance is MBSA and I don't understand why.

Comment: @MaxVernon: I am expecting to see only one instance, but there are three. Two of them explained in thread I'm refering too (although I don't clearly understand the answer). If I got it right, MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS correspond to DB Engine, and SQLEXPRESS to the SQL Server instance itself (which is something more than just DB Engine?). And origin of the third one I do not understand completely.

Comment: A SQL server has different auth modes because you made it so asking why to us doesn't makes sense. If it is showing 32 bit instance how could we tell you, may be somebody installed and you were not aware.

Comment: @Shanky: it was clean Windows system, only I had access to the machine and I did not do anything, only installed SQL Server and MBSA right after Windows deployment

Comment: Ok can you please run discovery report using this link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/petersad/archive/2009/11/13/sql-server-2008-discovery-report.aspx . Please add the report generated in question you asked

Comment: @Shanky: done, thanks, think I had do this from the very beginning

Comment: You are correct, you only have single instance of SQL server express. Now what other help you need ?

Comment: @Shanky: Why does MBSA shows mixed authentication mode for SQLEXRESS instance? It is Windows only for MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS and I choose Windows only during installation. And what is that 32-bit instance? Attached screenshots

Comment: That really seems strange, but I cannot see any 32 bit instance. One is instance SQLEXPRESS and other is its ID MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS. I will try to ask some expert on MBSA and will get back to you

Comment: @Shanky: Thanks a lot! I screened only the parts related to the first question. Added screenshot with 32-bit instance from the report.

Comment: If you have multiple instances installed, it can ONLY be because (a) you (or someone else) installed more than one instance, or (b) you (or someone else) installed some other software that created an instance for it's own purpose.  No other possibility exists.

Comment: @MaxVernon: Thanks! Then answer to the second question is that it is MBSA bug?